# How to using union query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have sample data like this:

Table : **SuratKeluar**

```
==========================================
Id   NoSuratKeluar   Perihal   TglSurat 
==========================================
a1      111           dataA   20-09-2014
a2      222           dataB   20-09-2014
a3      333           dataC   21-09-2004
a4      444           dataD   21-09-2004
```

Table : **SuratKeluarPermission**

```
==================================
Id   IdSuratKeluar   KodeJabatan
==================================
1        a1            0001
2        a1            0002
3        a3            0001
4        a4            0001
```

I want to display data from `SuratKeluar` with a condition on `SuratKeluarPermission`:

```
where KodeJabatan='0001'
```

Desired output would look like this:

```
==========================================
Id   NoSuratKeluar   Perihal   TglSurat 
==========================================
a1      111           dataA   20-09-2014
a3      333           dataC   21-09-2004
a4      444           dataD   21-09-2004
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180026.aspx), you need a [JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx). Try this:

```
SELECT SuratKeluar.Id, SuratKeluar.NoSuratKeluar, SuratKeluar.Perihal, SuratKeluar.TglSurat
FROM SuratKeluar
JOIN SuratKeluarPermission 
    ON SuratKeluar.Id = SuratKeluarPermission.IdSuratKeluar
WHERE SuratKeluarPermission.KodeJabatan = '0001'
```

Comment: okay, I'll try. later I will let you know whether it is true or still less. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here you can't use union since number of columns and data types are not same between these two tables. We can use join to get expected results, hopefully bellow query should provide the result:

```
SELECT
   SK.Id,
   SK.NoSuratKeluar,
   SK.Perihal, 
  SK.TglSurat 
FROM
   SuratKeluar AS SK INNER JOIN SuratKeluarPermission AS SKP 
   ON SK.ID = SKP.IdSuratKeluar 
WHERE
   SKP.KodeJabatan='0001';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve this using `INNER JOIN`.

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT a.Id,a.NoSuratKeluar,a.Perihal,a.TglSurat
FROM SuratKeluar a
JOIN SuratKeluarPermission b
ON a.Id=b.IdSuratKeluar
WHERE b.KodeJabatan='0001';
```

### **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8afc2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

I propose to filter `Id` by using subquery

```
select * from SuratKeluar
where Id in (
  select IdSuratKeluar from SuratKeluarPermission
  where KodeJabatan='0001');
```

or filter by `exists` statement

```
select * from SuratKeluar t
where exists (
  select * from SuratKeluarPermission
  where KodeJabatan='0001'
  and IdSuratKeluar=t.Id);
```